# SQL Server 2014 SP3 Slow query with big difference in Estimated number of rows and Actual number of rows

Tags: sql-server, cardinality

The below query is running slow and i suspect that the issue is because of a huge difference between Estimated number of rows and Actual number of rows with the SQL Server 2014 SP3. Unfortunately, I am not allowed to create the missing index as recommended by SQL Server.

```
SELECT
SUM(-J1.AMOUNT)
FROM
[AUDB_SUN].dbo.SALFLDGAU
 J1 
INNER JOIN SSRFACC J1CA ON J1CA.SUN_DB ='AU' AND J1CA.ACCNT_CODE=J1.ACCNT_CODE

WHERE
1=1
AND NOT ('A' like '%Z%' AND J1.JRNAL_SRCE IN ('B/F', 'CLRDN') AND J1.JRNAL_NO = 0 )

AND J1.JRNAL_NO <= 0663595
AND CASE 1 WHEN 1 THEN 'A' ELSE J1.ACCNT_CODE END
='A'
AND J1.PERIOD BETWEEN 1996001 AND 2021001
AND J1.ANAL_T0='181'
AND J1.ANAL_T1 BETWEEN '5000' AND '5999'
```

Comment: The version of SQL Server is 2014 SP3 standard

Comment: The plan has been copied to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BySMIrIWw